# Questions about the proof of $a+b$ and $ab$ (transcendental/algebraic)

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I have questions about the proof of:

Let $K \subset L$ be a field extension and $a,b \in L$ transcendental numbers over $K$.

How to show that $a+b$ and $ab$ are not both algebraic over $K$?

The proof is:

The formula is $[K(a,b):K]=[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)] \cdot [K(a+b,ab):K]$.

It exists a polynomial $(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab=0$ with roots $a,b$.

$\Rightarrow [K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)] \leq 2$

Suppose $a+b$ and $ab$ are both algebraic over $K$, then $[K(a+b,ab):K]<\infty$.

$\Rightarrow [K(a,b):K] <\infty$, and that is a contradiction to $a,b$ are transcendent over $K$.

My questions are: How to find the polynomial $x^2-(a+b)x+ab=0$ to see that $a,b$ are the roots? And why does it imply that $[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)] \leq 2$?

$\textbf{Another approach of the proof:}$

The formula is $[K(a,b):K]=[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)] \cdot [K(a+b,ab):K]$.

Let $m:=[K(a,b):K], p:=[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)]$ and $q=[K(a+b,ab):K]$.

Since $a,b$ are transcendent over $K$, it follows that $m=\infty$.

So it has to be shown that $p$ is finite, as $\Rightarrow q=\infty$ and $a+b,ab$ are transcendent and not algebraic

It's $K(a,b)=K(a+b,ab)$

$L:=K(a,b)$ contains $a$ and $b \Rightarrow K(a+b,ab) \subset K(a,b)$

To show that $L \subset M:=K(a+b,ab)$, it has to be shown that $a,b \in M$

It's $\frac{a+b}{ab} \in M$ since $a+b,ab \in M$

$\frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{a}{ab}+\frac{b}{ab}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a}\in M$ and also $\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{a} \in M$

$a=\frac{1}{b}(ab)\in M, b=\frac{1}{a}(ab)\in M$

$\Rightarrow K(a,b)=K(a+b,ab)$

$\Rightarrow p=1$

$\Rightarrow q=\infty$

$\Rightarrow a+b$ and $ab$ are not both algebraic over $K$

Is this right?

Comment: You have constructed the polynomial by multiplying $x-a$ and $x-b$, which tells you the roots are $a,b$.

Comment: Where is says 'Suppose $a+b$ and $ab$ are both transcendental over $K$', it should say 'Suppose $a+b$ and $ab$ are both algebraic over $K$'. This assumption implies that extending $K(a+b,ab)$ with a root of the polynomial $p(x)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$ results in an extension of degree at most $2$. Recall that such extension is isomorphic to $K(a+b,ab)[x]/(p(x))$. Each element of the latter quotient has a representative consisting of the remainder of a polynomial in $K(a+b,ab)[x]$ by division by $p(x)$. Since $p$ has degree $2$ the remainders have degree at most $1$. ...

Comment: ... This is, they are linear combinations of $1$ and $x$. So, $K(a+b,ab)[x]/(p(x))$ can be generated over $K(a+b,ab)$ by a set of two elements $1,x$. This tells you that $[K(a+b,ab)[x]/(p(x)),K(a+b,ab)]\leq 2$.

Comment: See your [former question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478831/ab-and-ab-are-not-both-transcendental-field-extension).

Comment: But doesn't it follow from $x^2-(a+b)x+ab=0$ that $[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)] \leq 2$?

Comment: I tried it with another approach in the edit. Is this correct, too?

Answer (score 1):

The comments provide an explanation of the proof provided by your text: here's an alternate approach.

If $a+b$ and $ab$ are algebraic, then $(a+b)^2-4ab=a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2$ is algebraic. Since the field of algebraic numbers are closed under roots, this implies that $a-b$ is algebraic.

But, this then shows that $(a+b)-(a-b)=2b$ is algebraic, a clear contradiction.

Comment: Alright, I tried it with another approach and edited it. Is it correct, too?